# Safety of ptrace on x86_64

Tags: c, x86-64, ptrace

From Wikipedia:

> `long`: Long signed integer type. Capable of containing at least the [−2,147,483,647, +2,147,483,647] range; thus, it is at least 32 bits in size.

From `man ptrace`:

> ```
> long ptrace(enum __ptrace_request request, pid_t pid,
>             void *addr, void *data);
> ```

Remember that signed overflow is undefined behavior in C. The registers on x86_64 store 64-bit values.

Is it thus unsafe to read the contents of the registers (e.g. `ORIG_RAX`) with `ptrace` on x86_64?

Comment: `ptrace()` is platform-specific for Linux and on Linux x86_64, `long` is 64 bit (it uses the LP64 model)

Comment: Note that when reading registers (`PTRACE_GETREGS`), values are returned via `data` arument, not returned as return value ("On success, PTRACE_PEEK* requests return the requested data, while other requests return zero" according to man).

Comment: You missed a very important part of that quote. "at least"

Comment: Why so many downvotes? I did not know that every Linux is guaranteed to have a 64-bit long.

Comment: Two downvotes is nowhere near a lot ("so many", as you say), and not knowing something does not make a question useful. You are expected to do some research first, before asking.

Comment: This is just the first of many warts you'll encounter while learning ptrace. It might be better if its return value were standardized as `union { intmax_t; void *; }`, but I think any standards committee charged with rationalizing ptrace's interface would run away in horror before they got that far.

Comment: Hmm, if that definition of `ptrace` is used on every platform, I guess that means the ABI used by Linux on any architecture has `long` at least as wide as a pointer.  Interesting.  I knew that was the case for the x86-64 System V ABI that Linux uses, but didn't know about other architecture ABIs.

Answer (score 2):

`ptrace()` is not specified in POSIX. It's available on Linux and some other systems, all of which have in common that they use the [LP64 data model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) on `x86_64`. With these platforms, you **have** 64bit `long`. So, this is safe.

(Windows on the other hand uses LLP64, only `long long` is 64bit on `x86_64`)

Answer (score 0):

When you something like `ptrace` you are not talking about the C standard. You have fixed the target/platform/architecture(/compiler). These things fix the implementation.

Under this implementation, the behavior happening is defined and is safe(because it uses 64 bit size for `long`).

So no, it is not unsafe. But it would be unsafe if you just copied the compiled binaries and used on another target.